# I want to store multiple logs at /var/logs, into different folders by the name of the log files

Tags: logging, linux-headers

For example, create folder syslog and store all syslog*.gz into that folder and so on..

Comment: You want to use logrotate (https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). See option 'olddir'.

Comment: @LupusE Can you post an answer which OP can accept?

Answer (score 0):

As requested, as answer.

The renaming of the logfiles is done with the program logrotate.

Take a look at the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate), and especially at the Option **olddir**. The configuration can be found in `/etc/logrotate.conf` and/or `/etc/logrotate.d/*`